# What is the appropriate way of collecting data from a form that has PartialView that change based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a `ParentView` that has few fields of its own. This `ParentView` renders a single `PartialView` out of 3 different PartialViews based on dropdown selected in the ParentView. So there is `PartialViewA`, `PartialViewB` and `PartialViewC`. At a time only one will be rendered. Each has its own Table ie. model class.

`Eg: PartialViewAModel:ParentViewModel` .. and so on.

One of the ways I could think of collecting data is by using `FormCollection`.
So if `dropdownvalue` is A I would know what keys I have to pick and where to store.

But is there a more elegant way for binding the data? Had there been only one view and model I could have simply used Modelclass in the binding. Eg: ublic

```
  [HttpPost]
ActionResult Create(CustomerClass cust)
```

Comment: You could use an ajax post and switch between different action, otherwise i would put a reference for each child ViewModel in the parent one (imho this isn't too bad).

Comment: @GiovanniRomio There is one submit button that submits entire form (parent and partial). I have all the keys(ones that belong to parent and the ones that belong to the rendered partial view) in my formcollection object. But I was wondering if I could use `UpdateModel` etc on this object to fill an instance of ParentModel and Partialview model , that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a Parent View Model that has child Partial View Models, like this:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        PartialViewModel1 = new PartialViewModel1();
        PartialViewModel2 = new PartialViewModel2();
        PartialViewModel3 = new PartialViewModel3();
    }

    public string PartialViewType { get; set; } /* Value to determine which view to show */

    public PartialViewModel1 PartialViewModel1 { get; set; }
    public PartialViewModel2 PartialViewModel2 { get; set; }
    public PartialViewModel3 PartialViewModel3 { get; set; }
}
```

Where the Partial View Models, for example `PartialViewModel1`, have the properties unique to that view model, like this:

```
public class PartialViewModel1
{
    public string Property1_1 { get; set; }
    public string Property1_2 { get; set; }
    public string Property1_3 { get; set; }
}
```

You can specify your Parent View so that it has a form which contains the partial views, which can be toggled on the client side with a bit of JavaScript (which I haven't included but should be simple enough :) ):

```
@model Models.ParentViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PartialViewType) /* Change this to a drop down */

    @Html.Partial("PartialView1")
    @Html.Partial("PartialView2")
    @Html.Partial("PartialView3")

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

The Partial Views look like this, e.g. for `PartialView1`:

```
@model Models.ParentViewModel
<h3>Partial View 1</h3>
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PartialViewModel1.Property1_1)</p>
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PartialViewModel1.Property1_2)</p>
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PartialViewModel1.Property1_3)</p>
```

So now you can submit to the `Update` action on your controller by passing through the `ParentViewModel`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(ParentViewModel model)
{
    // Do whatever processing required.
    // You can switch on model.PartialViewType to process the appropriate PartialView fields

    return View("Index", model);
}
```

When you submit, the model should then contain whatever has been submitted in the appropriate Partial View Model properties.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Depending on the data-set size, this may not be very efficient. This would probably be a good example of "try it and refactor later" though, as it would definitely work. *+1 for working solution that sticks to the basics of MVC.*

Comment: Does not seem to be filling PartialViewModel on post. All properties are null. I am using html input fields with `name="Property1_1 " `

Comment: Check your `@model` declaration at the top of the PartialView view is set to `@model Models.ParentViewModel` (as in the answer). This should result in the following HTML being emitted `<input id="PartialViewModel1_Property1_1" name="PartialViewModel1.Property1_1" type="text" value="" />`, which should then bind to the model correctly on post.